# Entity Framework/ Linq - groupby and having clause

Tags: linq, entity-framework

Given the query below

```
       public TrainingListViewModel(List<int> employeeIdList)
        {
            this.EmployeeOtherLeaveItemList =
                CacheObjects.AllEmployeeOtherLeaves
                .Where(x => x.OtherLeaveDate >= Utility.GetToday() &&
                    x.CancelDate.HasValue == false &&
                    x.OtherLeaveId == Constants.TrainingId)
                .OrderBy(x => x.OtherLeaveDate)
                .Select(x => new EmployeeOtherLeaveItem
                {
                    EmployeeOtherLeave = x,
                    SelectedFlag = false
                }).ToList();
        }
```

I want to put in the employeeIdList into the query.
I want to retrieve all of the x.OtherLeaveDate values where the same x.OtherLeaveDate exists for each join where x.EmployeeId = (int employeeId in employeeIdList)

For example if there are EmployeeIds 1, 2, 3 in employeeIdList and in the CacheObjects.AllEmployeeOtherLeaves collection there is a date 1/1/2001 for all 3 employees, then retreive that date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to thank @IronMan84 and @GertArnold for helping me along, and I will have to admonish myself for not being clearer in the question. This is the answer I came up with. No doubt it can be improved but given no one has responded to say why I will now tick this answer.

```
   var numberOfEmployees = employeeIdList.Count;


var grp = CacheObjects.AllEmployeeOtherLeaves.Where(
                    x =>
                    x.OtherLeaveDate >= Utility.GetToday() 
                    && x.CancelDate.HasValue == false
                    && x.OtherLeaveId == Constants.TrainingId 
                    && employeeIdList.Contains(x.EmployeeId))
                    .GroupBy(x => x.OtherLeaveDate)
                    .Select(x => new { NumberOf = x.Count(), Item = x });

            var list =
                grp.Where(item => item.NumberOf == numberOfEmployees).Select(item => item.Item.Key).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

If I read you well it should be something like

```
var grp = this.EmployeeOtherLeaveItemList =
    CacheObjects.AllEmployeeOtherLeaves
    .Where(x => x.OtherLeaveDate >= Utility.GetToday()
             && x.CancelDate.HasValue == false
             && x.OtherLeaveId == Constants.TrainingId
             && employeeIdList.Contains(x.EmployeeId)) // courtesy @IronMan84
    .GroupBy(x => x.OtherLeaveDate);

if (grp.Count() == 1)
{
    var result = g.First().Select(x => new EmployeeOtherLeaveItem
    {
        EmployeeOtherLeave = x,
        SelectedFlag = false
    })
}
```

First the data is grouped by `OtherLeaveDate`. If the grouping results in exactly one group, the first (and only) `IGrouping` instance is taken (which is a list of `Leave` objects) and its content is projected to `EmployeeOtherLeaveItem`s.

Answer (score 1):

To the where statement add "&& employeeIdList.Contains(x.EmployeeId)"

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do here, then. Are you trying to only grab the dates if all of the employees in the id list have that same date?

Comment: Is the relationship between Employee and EmployeeOtherLeave a one-to-many?